# div class and id conflict in css whilst trying to position and resize

Tags: html, css

I was trying to use top, left and right to position certain image in my webpage. The positioning was working fine when my code was this

```css
#something{
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="something"><img src="#"/></div>
```

But when I implement a class on said element, i.e

```css
.class123{
  height:70px;
  width:70px;
}


#something{
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:25%;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="something" class="class123"><img src="#"/></div>
```

My image's size suddenly changed according to how I specify my top, left values,  not my height and width. Here's actual code

```css
html { 
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
@font-face{
 font-family:myFirstFont;
 src: url(FORCED_SQUARE.ttf);
}


/* logo section */
#logo{
display: block;
 width: 13%;
 margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

/* Icon section */

.icons{    
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition:  all 1 ease;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
#fbicon{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -73.75px;
 left: 25%;
}
#liin{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -73.75px;
 right: 25%;
}
.icons:hover{
    transform:  scale(1.5);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Bienvenue!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <link rel="shorcut icon" href="favicon (2).ico"/>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Logo section -->  
 <img id="logo" src="logo.png"/>

 <!-- Icons section -->
 <div id="fbicon" class="icons"><a href="#"><img src="icons/facebook.png"/></a> </div>  
 <div id="liin" class="icons"><a href="#"><img src="icons/linkedin.png"/></a></div>

 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I recommend you to set for example border: 1px solid red; on your .class123 so you can see it's behavior while editing

Comment: why would you have two attributes targeting the same element?  and obviously the id attribute is more specific than the class attribute hence why the CSS rules for id attribute is taking precedence

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I was trying to give certain properties to both of my ids while maintaining some aspects of the ids individual, that's why I used the class to do the job. It's also to avoid some other divs from sharing the same properties these two ids would have

Comment: @ChesterCheng you could surely accomplish the same using just classes? If you had a certain class that you only apply to these 2 elements and not others, is that not the same as what you are describing ?

Comment: @Kiz Do you mean change the ids to classes as well?

Comment: @ChesterCheng yeah. If you have specific classes that you only need to target certain elements, I would just use a class. Add that class only to those 2 elements, and not to the others. This is the same as using an ID